# Node orm2 return find() result

Tags: javascript, node.js, orm

In my Profile model i have this method:

```
// Check login and return object
checkLogin: function(username, password) {
        ProfileObj = Profile.find({username: username, password: password}).one(function(err, profile){
                         return profile;
                    });

        console.log(ProfileObj);
        return ProfileObj;
}
```

To call this method i use:

```
profile = req.models.profile();
ProfileObj = profile.checkLogin('test', 'test');
```

Unfortunatelly i do not get the object i want, i am getting the model, not the instance. The "profile" var inside the find() callback is what i want, but is not returning that. Instead, ProfileObj its the entire model.

```
{ find: [Function],
  only: [Function],
  limit: [Function],
  skip: [Function],
  offset: [Function],
  order: [Function],
  orderRaw: [Function],
  count: [Function],
  remove: [Function],
  first: [Function],
  last: [Function],
  each: [Function],
  run: [Function],
  success: [Function],
  fail: [Function],
  all: [Function],
  where: [Function],
  one: [Function],
  beforeCreate: [Function],
  afterCreate: [Function],
  beforeSave: [Function],
  afterSave: [Function],
  beforeValidation: [Function],
  beforeRemove: [Function],
  afterRemove: [Function],
  afterLoad: [Function],
  afterAutoFetch: [Function],
  extendsTo: [Function],
  model:
   { [Function]
     allProperties:
      { username: [Object],
        name: [Object],
        email: [Object],
        password: [Object],
        id: [Object] },
     settings: { set: [Function], get: [Function], unset: [Function] },
     drop: [Function],
     sync: [Function],
     get: [Function],
     find: [Function],
     all: [Function],
     one: [Function],
     count: [Function],
     aggregate: [Function],
     exists: [Function],
     create: [Function],
     clear: [Function],
     beforeCreate: [Function],
     afterCreate: [Function],
     beforeSave: [Function],
     afterSave: [Function],
     beforeValidation: [Function],
     beforeRemove: [Function],
     afterRemove: [Function],
     afterLoad: [Function],
     afterAutoFetch: [Function],
     hasOne: [Function],
     hasMany: [Function],
     extendsTo: [Function] },
  options:
   { only: [ 'id', 'username', 'name', 'email', 'password' ],
     id: [ 'id' ],
     table: 'profile',
     driver:
      { config: [Object],
        opts: [Object],
        customTypes: {},
        query: [Object],
        db: [Object],
        aggregate_functions: [Object],
        uid: '2d7089091970609caded514e621b51a7' },
     conditions: { username: 'test', password: 'test' },
     associations: [],
     limit: undefined,
     order: null,
     merge: null,
     offset: undefined,
     newInstance: [Function] } }
```

Can you please tell me how do i correctly return the "profile" found in the find() callback.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not possible since node.js it using async code.

Comment: This is possible, you need to use ORMs methods. See my reply below.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a method in your models, like so:

```
models.profile = db.define('profile', {
    id: { type: 'serial', key: true },
    another_column: { type: 'text' }
}, {
   methods: {
       checkLogin: function (username, password) {
           models.profile.one({ username, password }, (err, user) => {
               return user;
           });
       }
    }
}
```

Since you have, in theory, a username and a password from the form submission, you can do the following:

```
req.models.profile.find({ username: username }, (err, user) => {
    return user.checkLogin(user.username, password);
});
```

Good luck!